# Value passing from Tab to Script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, jquerymobile

**I am trying to call the value called 'a.id' in my script functions**

```
 <apex:column value="{!a.id}" headerValue="Publication SFDC Id" id="ID"/> 

                  <script>
                         var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

                        j$(document).ready(function(){
                            j$("#Submit").click(function() 
                                { 
                                var input = String(document.getElementById("ID").value);
```

**Is it possible? If not how can I do it? Thanks in advance**

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this - 
 Assuming "a" is controller side variable.

```
<script>
alert('{!a.id}');
</script>
```

This will give proper values of the controller variable.

Do let me know if it helps.

Thanks,

Ray